# only last record of database being returned JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection

I have a login page and the connection to my database is set up and is working perfectly when 1 record is visible in the database but when there are 2 entries (2 admin users) only the last entry works for the login and not the original and can't figure out why! below shows the entire code that I have created so i would appreciate if someone could give me some insight into this issue, thanks!

```
 package securitySystem;

 import java.awt.*;

 import javax.swing.*;

 import java.sql.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

public class loginPage extends JFrame {

public static void main (String args[]){
    loginPage gui= new loginPage ();
    gui.setSize (400, 400);
    gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setTitle("Login Page");

}   

JLabel lblUserName= new JLabel("UserName:");
JTextField txtUserName= new JTextField(15);
JLabel lblPassword= new JLabel("Password:");
JTextField txtPassword= new JTextField(15);
JButton btnForgotten= new JButton("Forgotten Login");
JButton btnLogin= new JButton("Login");

public loginPage (){
    setLayout (null);

    //JLabel lblUserName= new JLabel("UserName:");
    lblUserName.setBounds(100,100,110,30);
    add(lblUserName);

    //JTextField txtUserName= new JTextField(15);
    txtUserName.setBounds(170,100,110,30);
    add(txtUserName);

    //JLabel lblPassword= new JLabel("Password:");
    lblPassword.setBounds(100,150,110,30);
    add(lblPassword);

    //JTextField txtPassword= new JTextField(15);
    txtPassword.setBounds(170,150,110,30);
    add(txtPassword);

    //JButton btnLogin= new JButton("Login");
    btnLogin.setBounds(100,300, 70, 30);
    add(btnLogin);
    actionlogin();

    //JButton btnForgotten= new JButton("Forgotten Login");
    btnForgotten.setBounds(175,300, 130, 30);
    add(btnForgotten);


}

public void actionlogin()
{
    btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
        {

            String username = txtUserName.getText();
            String password = txtPassword.getText();

            String databaseUsername = "";
            String databasePassword = "";

            String dataSourceName = "securitySystem";
            String dbUrl = "jdbc:odbc:" + dataSourceName;

            try{
                //Type of connection driver used    
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                //Connection variable or object param: dbPath, userName, password
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, "", "");

                Statement statement = con.createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select username, password  from employee");

                while (rs.next()) {
                    databaseUsername = rs.getString("username");   //resultSet.getString("username");
                    databasePassword = rs.getString("password");
                }  

                statement.close();
                con.close();
            }catch (Exception e) {
                try {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Compare the user entered info to the database info
            if(username.equals(databaseUsername) && password.equals(databasePassword)) 
            {
                adminMenu gui =new adminMenu();
                gui.setSize (400, 400);
                gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                gui.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
            }
            else 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Wrong Password / Username");
                txtUserName.setText("");
                txtPassword.setText("");
                txtUserName.requestFocus();
            }               
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is becasue

```
while (rs.next()) {
                    databaseUsername = rs.getString("username");   //resultSet.getString("username");
                    databasePassword = rs.getString("password");
                }
```

For the 1st row `rs.next()` returns `true` `databaseUsername` and `databasePassword` gets the 1st record.Now for the 2nd row rs.next() again returns true so `databaseUsername` and `databasePassword` gets the 2nd record and now rs.next() return false so control comes out of the loop and in the final  `databaseUsername` and `databasePassword` has the datas of the last row

You are trying to this part if the username matches with databaseusername

```
adminMenu gui =new adminMenu();
                gui.setSize (400, 400);
                gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                gui.setVisible(true);
            dispose();
```

try this way

```
while(rs.next())
{
if(username.equals(rs.getString("username")) && password.equals(rs.getString("password"))
{
 adminMenu gui =new adminMenu();
                    gui.setSize (400, 400);
                    gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    gui.setVisible(true);
                dispose();
}
}
```

Comment: yes it opens the admin window if the username and password are correct but I don't want them to overwrite every time it loops through the database so how do I do this?

Comment: @Adam check my answer under *try this way*

Comment: that works perfectly but the only issue is now that I'm receiving the error message even when the login is successful! I will have to wok through my code to try and figure out why this is happening

Comment: @Adam you might not have removed the code written in else part.Its a best practice to solve by yourself,If you still get any error then post another question showing clearly your problem.

Comment: its going through the database and checks if the username and password are present and if not it fires the error message and because there are 2 entries it is firing the message twice!

Answer (score 0):

Look at your code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    databaseUsername = rs.getString("username");   //resultSet.getString("username");
    databasePassword = rs.getString("password");
}
```

What will happen if there are multiple rows? The loop will run multiple times, overwriting the values in `databaseUsername` and `databasePassword` each time. When it's done, it will contain the values of the last time the loop ran.

(Also, storing plain text passwords in a database is a really bad idea.)

Comment: show how would I counteract this problem! I should have noticed that from the beginning!

Comment: it is only a simple program that I am creating so the passwords will be fine for what i'm trying to do

Comment: That depends on what you want. What exactly do you expect your program to do?

Comment: I have two admin users in my database and I want them both to have the ability to sign in to the system!

Comment: The simplest way is looking up the password with the query: `select password from employee where username=?` (use a `PreparedStatement` and set `username` for the parameter). If no records are found the user does not exist; otherwise you check if the password that was entered is equal to what you got from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You looping through records then overwriting the same string. A login should be unique anyway so you should check it in an if statement instead.

Comment: how do I stop overwriting them and give them ability to hold multiple record (if this is possible)!